# Is this a proper MVC design ? Advices on MVC design an communication to thread

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, model-view-controller

The last day i read lots and lots of tutorials and blogs about the MVC pattern. Now I pretty much understand the concept, but it seemed to me that every tutorial showed another concept to implement this pattern in Java. So I decided to write my own application and then ask you the higher skilled programmers for advice. (Learning by doing is kind of my thing) .

So I dont want to loose to many words about my initial thought but I will show you my code :

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {enter code here
    public static void main(String[] args){

        MainController controller = new MainController();
        controller.initView();
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
public class MainController implements ActionListener{

private ExtractorStatics stat;
private MainView mainview;
private BusinessExtractor bExtractor;
private InfoboxTextPane infobox;
private BufferedImage logoGS;

public MainController(){
     stat = new Statics(); 
     model = new Model();
     mainview   = new MainView();
}
public void initView(){
    if(mainview!=null){
        mainview.setActionListener(this);
        mainview.setItemListener(new ComboBoxItemListener(this));
        mainview.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    if(command.equalsIgnoreCase(stat.SCAN_ACTION_COMMAND)){
        this.quickScanButtonAction();
    }
}


private void quickScanButtonAction(){
    infobox = mainview.getInfobox();
    ProcessingInformation information = model.quickScan();
    InputStream informationStream = information.getInformationStream();
    BufferedReader infoReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(informationStream));
    String line;
    try {
    while ((line = infoReader.readLine()) != null) {
                infobox.appendLine(line);
            }

            infoReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("End reached");
    }
    else
        infobox.appendLine("Bitte Eingabe überprüfen.");
}
public void comboBoxChanged() {
    //do some fancy stuff
}
   }

 class ComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener{
        MainController mc;
    public ComboBoxItemListener(MainController mc){
        this.mc=mc;
    }
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        mc.comboBoxChanged();
    }   
}

MainView Class:

    public class MainView extends JFrame {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 559229524422932258L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txt_stichwort,txt_loc;
    private JButton btn_quickscan;
    private JTable table;
    private JLabel label;
    public  InfoboxTextPane txtpn_infobox;
    private String lineSep;
    private final JComboBox<String> combobox;
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainView() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        lineSep=System.lineSeparator();
        Statics stats=new Statics();



        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 620);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        txt_subject= new JTextField();
        txt_stichwort.setBounds(88, 47, 318, 20);
        pan_suche.add(txt_stichwort);
        txt_stichwort.setColumns(10);

        combobox = new JComboBox<String>();
        combobox.setBounds(88, 16, 318, 20);
        pan_suche.add(combobox);
        combobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Item1", "Item2"}));

        txt_loc = new JTextField();
        txt_loc.setBounds(88, 79, 318, 20);
        pan_suche.add(txt_loc);
        txt_loc.setColumns(10);



        btn_quickscan = new JButton("Quick Scan");
        btn_quickscan.setActionCommand(stats.SCAN_ACTION_COMMAND);
        btn_quickscan.setBounds(10, 23, 130, 30);
        pan_dos.add(btn_quickscan);

        //a few more buttons that have other action commands defined by statics
        //more labels and other GUI components


    }
    public InfoboxTextPane getInfobox(){
        return this.txtpn_infobox;
    }
    public String getSearchSubject(){
        return this.txt_stichwort.getText();
    }

    public String getSearchLocation(){
        return this.txt_loc.getText();
    }
    public String getSearchWebsite(){
        return (String)this.combobox.getSelectedItem();
    }
    public JComboBox<String> getComboBox(){
        return this.combobox;
    }
    public JLabel getLogoLabel(){
        return this.label;
    }

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener al){
        try {

            btn_quickscan.addActionListener(al);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setItemListener(ItemListener il){
        this.combobox.addItemListener(il);
    }
    }
```

Model Class:

```
public class Model {
private ExecutorService exeService;

public Model(){
    exeService =Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}

public ProcessingInformation quickScan(){ 
    QuickScanRoutine qs = new QuickScanRoutine();
    Future<String> result = exeService.submit(qs);
    return qs.getProcessingInformation(); 
}

}
```

Routine Class (Callable):

```
public class QuickScanRoutine implements Callable<String> {
    private ProcessingInformation pi;
    private BufferedWriter writer;



public QuickScanRoutine(){
    pi = new ProcessingInformation();
    PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pis;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pos));

    try {
        pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
        pi.setInformationStream(pis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public ProcessingInformation getProcessingInformation(){
    return this.pi;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {

    //ofcourse this isnt the real purpose of this Class but I want to     `demonstrate writing to the stream`

    for(int i =0; i<100;i++){
        writer.write("Hello");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    }
    writer.close();
    return "Routine has been executed sucessfully!";
}

}
```

Processing Information:

```
public class ProcessingInformation {
PipedInputStream informationStream,resultDataStream;

    public void setInformationStream(PipedInputStream info) {
        this.informationStream = info;
    }
    public void setResultDataStream(PipedInputStream data){ 
//I will need this stream for further tasks
        this.resultDataStream = data;
    }

    public InputStream getInformationStream(){
    if(informationStream!=null){
        return informationStream;
    }
    else
        return null;
}

public InputStream getResultDataStream(){
    if(informationStream!=null){
        return informationStream;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
}
```

I tried to shorten up the code as far as posible, but tried to keep it in context, so you can understand the whole construct. 
My main questions are:

- Is this a proper MVC Design ?
- Is this a suitable way to comunicate from this model thread to the view ? (PipedStream)

These would be my main questions but I am thankful and open to all of your advices.

Comment: Take a look at my [Java Swing File Browser](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=637) article.  I illustrate one way of coding a Swing application using the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer from Abhi Beckert on some aspects - typically the following:

1. It is never acceptable for the model to communicate with anything other than the model.
2. The view should communicate only with other view objects and not have knowledge about the controller.

In addition the Controller must know anything about the composition of the View since this would couple the Controller and the View. And this coupling would mean that were you needed to change the view representation or for that matter provide a choice of various  data representations to a user you would have to write a new controller for each of the representation. Let me make this point concrete by stating an example.

When you take open a Word document in a Word Processor like MS-Word, the page can various layout such as Portrait, Landscape, Print and Html. In each of these layouts, the visible user elements are different. However the data is the same. Hence the most logical way to approach the problem would be to either:

- Have the controller send a command to the model to update the appropriate view.
- Have the controller query the model to obtain the data and simply pass the obtained data to the view for rendering.

I went through the code that you have posted and identified that your controller knows about the contents of the view for e.g. the `MainController` calls into `MainView.getinfobox()`.Based on the above explanation, you would want to change that.

As about the second question related to sending data using a **PipedStream**, I do not see anything technically wrong in it - since a stream is a also a container of data. But, I have personally not seen or come across until now a design or code snippet that would follow this pattern.

Hope this helps

Comment: In an MVC application, it's allowable for the view to read data directly from the model.  Yes, the view has to have an instance of the model, but the model is still decoupled from the view.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I agree, but what I am saying is that the controller must know anything about the composition of the View.

Comment: Generally, I pass an instance of the frame (view) class and an instance of the model class to each of the many controllers that need to know.  The frame class has methods for updating / refreshing the view.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer to this question, because it was to long to post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no java programmer but I know MVC well:

If looks to me like your model classes should be doing more work. There seems to be some model code in your controller and view.

Also, it is never acceptable for the model to communicate with anything, except other parts of the model.

Same goes for the view — it should only communicate with other view objects.

All communication code goes in the controller later. The model and view should have arbitrary callbacks and so on that are configured and used by objects in the controller layer.

The  point of MVC is to make your model and view completely independent of the rest of your code. They should have zero outside dependencies.

Comment: But the model just communicates by a getter method. So the controller gets it. And then another model class writes to a stream. Is this deprecated aswell ? I Though the whole point of MVC was that you could use the model by its own. Like calling the quickscan() Method from any other UserInterface or from the console? Or did I get this wrong ?

Comment: @user3187049 Right, in your code the model isn't connected. However you have "model" code inside your controller and view code. All of that code needs to be moved into the model class (or classes), and you need to move it in such a way that it doesn't know about the controller or the view.

Comment: Note that the "model" is not the data in your app. The "model" is all code that operates on the data. So, the way your code is now, your controller is *part* of the model because it has model code inside it. You should separate that out.

Comment: Also, as always, rules are made to be broken. MVC is a guideline/best practice, but you can break the rules if you have a good reason (eg: performance).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something wrong in my understanding of the model class. Now I think the model is just the data that wants to be presented by the view. 
But before I thought the model is the business logic of my application. So my understanding is now:

The view contains all the graphical elements and has an instance of the controller since the view needs to implement the controller as listener for the actions performed on the form. (Buttonclicks etc.) But the view shouldnt contain any logic as far as posible.

The controller shouldn't contain real logic either it just handles the actions on the form and calls methods in the model. Therefore the controller needs to have an instance of both the view and the model.

The model contains all the data that wants to be shown in the view and invokes methods of the business logic in order to manipulate this data or do other internal processes.

- Is my understanding about right ?

I few other question that I have refering to the MVC Pattern:

- In a tutorial I saw an implementation of the MVC Pattern where the view was an Observer and the model was the Observable (Observer Pattern). That seems logic to me since the model reprents the data that shall be shown in the view. And the view needs to react to changes of the data of the model. But is this a suitable way to implement the realationship between the model an the view?
- Is it possible to have multiple model classes for one single form ? For example one model for a table, and another for a textpane ?
- Is it a suitable way or even the best way to implement all the interfaces that are need for buttonactions etc. in the controller and set them so the buttons in the view by a setter method ?
- Prahalad you said:

> I went through the code that you have posted and identified that your controller knows about the contents of the view for e.g. the MainController calls into MainView.getinfobox().Based on the above explanation, you would want to change that.

Does that mean that the controller should not manipulate the form at all ? I now think that the view just manipulates itself by the data the model provides, because the view "observes" the data of model and than changes itself. Is that correct ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.  No one here can tutor you in learning MVC.  There are other web sites where you can hire a tutor to help you learn MVC.

Comment: Okay sorry, but I really dont expect anybody to tutor me but I read a lot of tutorial an textes about that topic and now I still have some questions. Thats why I asked concrete questions and most of them are even yes no question. So Im only asking kindly for somebody to answer these question. Because reading blogs and tutorials helped me out a lot, but these are the questions that remained to me.

Comment: The model is not just the data, the model is the data and all code that touches the data.